# How to set varchar datatype in function?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I have an issue in my code where i took this : `(ApliEMAIL int)` in below code but when i execute function it return empty values because in table i took email filed as `varchar`.

When i write code with this `(ApliEMAIL varchar)` it does not create function and gives error.

```
DELIMITER $$

#DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_appli_name`$$

CREATE FUNCTION get_appli_name_by_email(ApliEMAIL int) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
DECLARE A_NAME VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT"";

  SELECT apli_fname  INTO   A_NAME
  FROM   tbl_signup
  WHERE  apli_email = ApliEMAIL;

  RETURN A_NAME;

END$$

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$

#DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_appli_name`$$

CREATE FUNCTION get_appli_name_by_email(ApliEMAIL varchar) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
DECLARE A_NAME VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT"";

  SELECT apli_fname  INTO   A_NAME
  FROM   tbl_signup
  WHERE  apli_email = ApliEMAIL;

  RETURN A_NAME;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please add the error you get to your question (use [Edit])

Answer (score 0):

I tested your function. I got this error.

> ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

By the way, in the future, when you are asking for help with an error, **include the error message in your post.** Help us to help you! Don't make us guess!

Read the documentation about `READS SQL DATA` here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html

So I added that option to your function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_appli_name_by_email(ApliEMAIL VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE A_NAME VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT"";

  SELECT apli_fname  INTO   A_NAME
  FROM   tbl_signup
  WHERE  apli_email = ApliEMAIL;

  RETURN A_NAME;

END$$
```

It works now:

```
mysql> select get_appli_name_by_email('thefrog@muppets.org');
+------------------------------------------------+
| get_appli_name_by_email('thefrog@muppets.org') |
+------------------------------------------------+
| Kermit                                         |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Kaewin                                                                                                                                                   select get_appli_name_by_email(apli_email) from tbl_signup ,when i use this function like that format it give me error :MySQL said: Documentation #1172 - Result consisted of more than one row.But when i use this function in this format get_appli_name_by_email('thefrog@muppets.org') it give result please help me to correct my error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the length of the `ApliEMAIL`-parameter.

Insted of:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_appli_name_by_email(ApliEMAIL varchar)
```

you should have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_appli_name_by_email(ApliEMAIL varchar(255))
```

..or whatever the length of ApliEMAIL is.

Comment: @Sallkso I created function but it give me this error i know it is due to duplicate record but help me how to fix this issue.other wise code working fine                                                                                                                                  MySQL said: Documentation
#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

Answer (score 0):

You must add deterministic or reads sql data flag.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION get_appli_name_by_email(ApliEMAIL varchar(50)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN ifnull((SELECT apli_fname FROM tbl_signup WHERE  apli_email = ApliEMAIL LIMIT 1), '');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```